Room addition detachment from home problem
We have a room addition that was on home before we purchased it. First issue is that addition not built on concrete foundation, it's held up by 4 cinder blocks. This winter I noticed separation from the top of addition from home. Not visible from outside, however it's noticeable from inside. There's a vertical crack that's opening little by little. How do I fix the problem and stop further detachment from occurring?

Location might matter, but it looks like redo time, if you want the addition.  Would like to know how it pass inspection.

I don't know how it passed inspection. The previous owners probably did it without permission.

Photos, outside and inside,  might help people make better guesses. Sounds like inadequate foundation and/or the adequate connection to the frame of the house. May be minor settling, may be remove-and-rebuild; really needs someone local to come and evaluate it for you.

"it's held up by 4 cinder blocks." Cinder blocks alone are quite flimsy; I've broken one with bare hands (no, I'm not a martial arts expert). Better support is definitely needed.

@DrMoishePippik Properly installed cinder blocks are perfectly adequate supports for most residential construction; we're not given enough information about the addition to know that 4 is too few. The more relevant issue here is that without proper footings/foundation it doesn't matter what the blocks are made of or how many of them are used, differential settlement is inevitable.
